# Rel-time monitoring on Redundant PSU's

Tags: power-supply-unit, hpe

we're using 3 HP DL380 Servers with redundant power supplies and vmware esxi hypervisor is installed. is there a way to determine the actual status of the power supplies in real-time? current voltage input and output, amperage, etc. i cannot find it in vmare management. it would be nice to include it in our snmp network for real-time monitoring.

Comment: usually you can read that on the iLo interfaces

Answer (score 1):

HP server have something called **Integrated Lights Out** which is an out of band management card that can monitor and manage the server at hardware level and to provide remote support, the great feature of this management card is you don’t have to be physically standing in front of the server to see if you hard disk has amber light etc. A similar card called iDRAC can be found on Dell servers.

Just configure ILO with an IP address visible from your network and then you can directly access all the hardware data.

After that, you can access the GUI via the configured IP and configure your SNMP alert settings. On the Administration-Management page there's a SNMP Settings tab, which contains the SNMP Alerts section. [Here](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-a00045581en_us) is the documentation from HP on how to configure alerts.

Comment: thank you Sir! i've been itching over using that for weeks now but just don't have much time due to staffing gaps in our office. will definitely try that now that you've brought it up. thanks again!